# spring mvc - How to retrieve values from controller without creating a view

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I have a problem here and I need your help.

Im trying to retrieve an integer value from the controller to the jsp.

In my jsp I have an ajax call:

```
$("#hdnCustomerSize").load(contextPath+"/customer/size", function() {
// some codes
});
```

In my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/size")
public void getCustomerSize(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("customerSize", customerService.getCustomers().size());
}
```

My problem is Im getting an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'customer/size' in servlet with name 'tombuyandsell'.
```

I know Im getting this exception because I intentionally did not map this in `views.properties`. The reason is I only want to get the integer value `size` and not a whole jsp page. Please help.

Comment: Thanks to this question..i learnt something about ResponseBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@ResponseBody` annotation and return the int as a String. `@ResponseBody` will cause the return type to be written to the response HTTP body.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/size")
@ResponseBody
public String getGroupChatSize(Model model) {
   return Integer.toString(customerService.getCustomers().size());
}
```

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

Comment: How am I gonna store the value in my $("#hdnCustomerSize") since the value is not stored in the model?

Comment: @NinjaBoy using the load method your making an ajax call to this controller which returns the size of your list, it will be placed within the element you select with jquery.  If you just want to get the data and then perform some action use `$.post()`

Comment: I tried to use alert to display. Btw, the hdnCustomerSize is hidden form I placed somewhere in my jsp. I do this to display $("#hdnCustomerSize").load(contextPath+"/customer/size", function() {
  alert($("#hdnCustomerSize").val());
});         It just alerts an empty value.

Comment: Are you sure the request is getting mapped to the controller?  What happens if you put a breakpoint in the controller and debug, or if you use firebug to see what gets sent over the wire?

Comment: I know what is happening. I used debug and firefox. Its actually working but Im trying to access the value of hidden the wrong way. I tried to display using alert($("#hdnCustomerSize").val()); When I checked it on firebug I found out that the jquery .load is storing the value as inner html. So I tried alert($("#hdnCustomerSize").html()) and alas it displayed!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @NinjaBoy Awesome, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [@ResponseBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/size")
public int getGroupChatSize() {
    return customerService.getCustomers().size();
}
```